# Autofac - Decorate all components from a particular assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

So I want to do some profiling on a bunch of controllers which inherit from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`. In the project that's doing the profiling, we're registering them with

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Web.Modules.AutofacModule).Assembly)
    .As(type => new Autofac.Core.KeyedService("api", type));
```

Later on, I'm trying to register a decorator for each with

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<ApiController>(original => Decorate(original, profiler), 
    fromKey: "api");
```

where `Decorate` injects some profiling code via a [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) and returns the original.

I can resolve the controllers just fine:

```
scope.ResolveKeyed<RegistrationController>("api");
```

but the profiling code is never invoked, nor is `Decorate`.

My first thought was that maybe I need to register the controller components as `ApiController`'s, but dropping an `.As<ApiController>()` just below first snippet wasn't successful.

Any help would be super. This probably just boils down to my lack of Autofac-fu.

Comment: What does your `Decorate` method do?

Comment: Configures the controller passed to it, basically. It adds a simple `DelegatingHandler` I wrote to its list of `MessageHandlers`.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to do some profiling on a bunch of controllers which inherit from System.Web.Http.ApiController.

This is impossible. This has nothing to do with Autofac, but with the way ASP.NET Web API is designed.

Even though Web API Controllers derive from a common base class, ASP.NET Web API requires the original controller type to be used. In other words, when it requests a `HomeController` from the `IHttpControllerActivator`, it expects that exact type (or a sub type), but not a sibling type (another `ApiController` derivative).

I think this limitation exists because Web API uses reflection to find the actual action methods. But when you return a decorator, those methods are gone, because a decorator applies composition instead of inheritance. This is very different from how ASP.NET MVC is designed. MVC actually does allow controllers to be decorated, as it always invokes the `IController.Execute` method. Implementation `IController` is therefore MVC's only requirement for controllers.

So even if you configure Autofac to wrap any `ApiController` derivatives in a Decorator, Web API simply won't let you.

The way to apply Cross-Cutting Concerns around the invocation of action methods in Web API is through the use of delegating handlers.

Comment: Thanks @steven. I guess I'm still a bit confused -and perhaps I should've provided more context on this- because the `Decorate` method being invoked does _not_ return a derived class of `ApiController` which encapsulates an instance of the original controller type. Rather, it provides -or, at least, I want the scope to resolve- an instance of the requested type with a delegating handler tacked on.